C/C++ headers cannot be found during pip install
I'm trying to install a Python package (PySedSim) on Windows 11 with Pip. The instructions say to run "pip install .", which mostly works but I get the error "The C/C++ header for freetype (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found. You may need to install the development package.". I'm getting the same error for png.h. I installed both of them (including the development package through the wizard) and they're both in subfolders of C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32 which are in my PATH, but still have this error. Any thoughts on how to fix this? Thank you!
Edit: This was marked as a duplicate of 1717689, which was helpful to reference, but the solution didn't work for me. I added include paths for CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH to C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\include (as well as CPLUS and C_INCLUDE_PATH after referencing different posts) and still have the same issues. That post was about also about g++, which I'm not using.

You will want to include the necessary details to diagnose your issue if you truly believe the duplicate doesn’t answer your question.

@Ramhound Thanks! I'm having trouble thinking of other things that need to be added, does anything else come to mind? First post, sorry!
